# Can one view In scrollview but it will not scroll?

Tags: ios, scrollview

I make a view in scrollview, but I did not want it scroll with scrollview, can it fix in the bottom?

Comment: remove that view from scrollview and reduce your scrollview height..

Comment: @Prateek but the scroll view is the root view in the controller.I do not know how to add it.

Comment: change your root view from scrollview and set to view or make your scrollview scroll to off and add another scrollview inside that scrollview and make its height smaller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes in the scrollViewdidScroll delegate method update the frame of the subview which you need to fix.